# Linear interpolation - audio pitch shift

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, javasound, pitch-shifting

I am trying to do pitch shifting on a sample. I am using linear interpolation method.

If amount being pitched is a whole integer value, pitch is shifted cleanly. If the amount being pitch shifted is rational, the sound is heavily distorted. The implementation seems to work.

Here is my code, I tried to comment well.

```
public void generateOutTrack()
{
    Note currNote;
    float[] output=new float[pattern.getPlayTimeInSmps()];//returns total play time of pattern in #samples.


    float[] currSample=sample.getData();//the pcm data of the sample to be used
    int currPeriod=0;//length of next note in number of samples
    int outputPtr=0;//points to next sample in output buffer array
    float pitch;//amount to pitch sample by
    float linInt=0;//linear interpolater
    float phasePtr=0;//floating point index in sample
    int ptr=0;//integer index into sample

    JavAud.checkRange(currSample);

    while((currNote=pattern.nextNote())!=null)//each iteration plays one note
    {

        currPeriod=currNote.getPeriodInSmps();//length of current note in samples
        pitch=currNote.getPitch();//pitch of current note

        for(int i=0;i<currPeriod;i++)//run for length of note
        {   
            ptr=(int)phasePtr;//floor of floating point index
            linInt=phasePtr-ptr;

            //if we are not at end of sample copy data to output
            if(ptr<currSample.length*(1/pitch)-1)
            {

                //linear interpolation pitch shifting
                output[outputPtr]=(currSample[ptr+1]*linInt)+(currSample[ptr]*(1-linInt));

                //alternate pitch shifting by simple sample dropping(has less distortion)
                //output[outputPtr]=currSample[ptr];

            }
            else//else silent
            {
                output[outputPtr]=0;
            }   

            outputPtr++;
            phasePtr=phasePtr+pitch;
        }

        phasePtr=0;

    }
    JavAud.checkRange(output);
    WavFileWriter writer = new WavFileWriter();
    writer.writeWave(new WavFile(1, JavAud.GLB_SMP_RATE, output), "outputTone.wav");

}
```

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce/org).)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to do a pitch shift by resampling.  One common way to do better quality resampling than linear interpolation is to use a windowed Sinc low-pass filter as your interpolation kernel.  Pseudo-code for one (slow) method of windowed Sinc resampling is here: http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#3

Comment: I am not getting bad quality because of algorithm choice. I am getting bad quality because of bug in code somewhere. I am getting heavy distortion, and values way out of whack....not just aliasing from poor algorithm.